# "GrailsDomainException: Identity property not found, but required in domain class" only on WebSphere 7

Tags: grails, websphere

When starting my grails 2.5.3 app with the command "grails run-app" it starts with no issues. But when starting it on WebSphere 7 I am getting the following error:

```
context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Identity property not found, but required in domain class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.SHA1BytesCodec]
```

The mentioned class obviously isn't a domain class but for some reason grails thinks it is.

Usually restarting the app would work but not anymore. All I got this time was making it complain about a different class (also not a domain one, but a service one).

Comment: I would start with a brand new test app and a deployment if that works the compare the applicationContext.xml file in both your site and the new site to see what is the diff:  also search for Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]. Might give more ideas clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed at [Grails 3.1.x](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/10470/commits/1206227bb54a593d1cf6be6ceff53b9af2d90475) and [Grails 2.5.x](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/10453/commits/050c5ffa20622301c9684b3b2fc1ff042b6596d9).